# Compiling multiple packages using the command line in Java

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-construction, package, javac

Hi i have been using an IDE but now I need to run and compile from the command line.

The problem is that I have multiple packages and I have tried to find the answer but nothing has worked.

So I have

```
src/
  Support/ (.java files)
  Me/ (.java files) 
  Wrapers/ (.java files)
```

Do you know how to compile everything with javac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it (may require additional classpath elements via the `-cp` command line switch):

```
javac Support/*.java Me/*.java Wrapers/*.java
```

But if your build process gets more complex (and it will!), you should look into using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for build automation.

Comment: +1 - For an existing project with minimal external dependies, Ant is simpler than (for example) Maven.  His IDE may even be able to generate an initial "build.xml" file.

Comment: Thanks I tried this, it compiles everything but it does not generate the class structure so when I try to run my main it says ""main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Wrapper/java"

Comment: @Altober: the `java` tool expects *class names*, not file names, and especially not source file names. You probably need to do something like `java Wrapers.Wrapper`, assuming you have a class "Wrapper" inside a package "Wrapers"

Answer (score 10):

You should use build tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for such tasks.

In the initial stages, when the project is not very complex you can use the following line to compile, with appropriate classpath in place(as suggested by @Michael):

`javac Support/*.java Me/*.java Wrapers/*.java`

Comment: yeah the problem is that I need to do it in an external server and I am not able to install any aditional too.

Comment: You can unzip ant / maven in the same file system you store your code, you don't need to "install" them, so this is not going to prevent you from using either

Answer (score 6):

```
javac -d compiled $(find src -name *.java)
```

Comment: thanks I tried but I am getting "illegal variable names" do you knoe why. Thanks

Comment: maybe you need `-sourcepath src` as well. (or you need to specify the `src` directory as part of the classpath)

Comment: I have tried your snippet with my netbeans project and it works:

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to just use javac and standard UNIX commands you could to this:

```
find src -name \*.java -print0 | xargs -0 javac -d classes
```

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is javac -d (places where classes to be built and placed) -sourcepath (source of the package at the root) -cp (classpath of the dependencies which can again be classes folder where the classes are build and kept) full qualified name of the java file.

Ex javac -d classes -sourcepath src -cp classes src\com\test\FirstSample.java

The FirstSample.java contains the main method. Pacjage structure mentioned below.

**Before compiling**

HomeApp

--src

------com\test\FirstSample.java (First Sample using the FirstPojo.java)

------com\test\FirstPojo.java

--classes

**After compiling**

HomeApp

--src

------com\test\FirstSample.java (FirstSample.java using the FirstPojo.java)

------com\test\FirstPojo.java

--classes

------com\test\FirstSample.class (FirstSample.class using the FirstPojo.class)

------com\test\FirstPojo.class

Answer (score 1):

1. To compile Run below command [it will store all class files in classes folder]

   javac -d classes Support/*.java Me/*.java Wrapers/*.java

**Note : classes folder should be created first

2. To Run java application, run below command

   java -cp classes {mainfile_name}

Replace mainfile_name with your main file.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases Ant is overkill.  Just use a BAT file if you are in windows or a shell script (sh file) if you are in linux.  You can create a text file which includes all your javac commands and just run that file when you want to build.

For example, I use the following bat file to build one of my apps:

```
@echo off
echo Building Shazaam...

del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\engine\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\domain\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\persist\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\view\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\task\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\action\*.* /q
del classes\com\aepryus\shazaam\controller\*.* /q

javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\*.java        -classpath \lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepXML.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\engine\*.java -classpath \lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepXML.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\domain\*.java -classpath \lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\persist\*.java    -classpath \lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\view\*.java   -classpath \lib\Servlet.jar;\lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepXML.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\AepHTML.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\task\*.java   -classpath \lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\AepHTML.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\action\*.java -classpath \lib\Servlet.jar;\lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\AepHTML.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes
javac src\com\aepryus\shazaam\controller\*.java -classpath \lib\Servlet.jar;\lib\AepUtil.jar;\lib\AepXML.jar;\lib\AepRPC.jar;\lib\AepLoom.jar;\lib\AepHTML.jar;\lib\Sprout.jar;classes; -d classes

cd classes
jar cf ..\war\WEB-INF\lib\Shazaam.jar .
cd..

echo Complete
```

Comment: What if you refactor a package or add a new package, you have to touch this file every time?  Have a watch of http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/java-jee/zen-and-the-art-of-build-script-maintenance if you need convincing...

Comment: No idea about others.  But over the course of a project the amount of times I need to modify such a batch file is miniscule, if at all.  There are no doubt situations that Maven and Ant is warranted; but I have not encountered them.  Sometimes to kill a fly, a shutgun is not necessary (nor a nuke)

Answer (score 0):

to compile the java program as a whole package, you should execute the below command where the package is present (i.e your current location should have the folder which you are going to compile)

javac -d  <package_name>/*.java

is where your compiled class files are stored
<package_name> is either the package name or with its path

<package_name>/*.java

you can add multiple packages at once ,with this syntax , seperated by a space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).