# package does not work and jvm does not recognise classes

Tags: java, package, javac

I have made a console based banking system in my first Java assignment. Everything works well if I use default package but when I add a

```
   package bank;
```

at the top of all classes, it can not find classes and there are a lot of errors.
How can I solve it?

I searched a lot on Google but didn't understand this thing.

cmd path is ...

```
C:\Users\Shah\Desktop\Assignment1\src\Bank.java and other classes are also in the same folder.
```

kindly help me to understand this thing

I tried

```
     javac *.java
```

and it compiled

but when I tried to run the byte code by

```
     java Bank
```

it gives `java.Lang.NoClassDefFound` Error

Comment: When you compile, are you adding that package to the class path?

Comment: @Makoto i am trying to add classpath but it gives error class path not defined

Answer (score 1):

If you have just added the package line in you `classes.java`,

```
package bank;
```

then you need to change the structure of your applicationm by adding a new folder named `bank` then you `classes.java` that you have been add the link package in.

so you cmd path should look like this :

```
C:\Users\Shah\Desktop\Assignment1\src\bank\Bank.java
```

Comment: i added the bank folder and added all classes in it but it is still not working

Comment: You need also to check the cmd path as i mentioned above.

Comment: i changed it till bank

Comment: From your update, when you tried `javac *.java`, you are telling the compliter to comple any class exsit in any package, but when tried `javac Bank`, this considering the defual package, and i belive if you said `javac bank.Bank` it will work, you have to tell the compiler from which package compile classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create another folder 'bank' corresponding to **bank** package under **src** folder. **src/bank**

place all classes under **src/bank** which defines `package bank;`

Also you can compile mutiple files using  `javac com\pack1\pack2\one\*.java com\pack1\pack2\two\.*java`

then try to run.

**For example** image below shows package pack1 which contains a Test.java class with package definition
[image: Image shows compiling different java classes]

For more info [**refer this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140512/how-to-compile-multiple-java-files-when-there-are-java-files-in-other-packages)