# Compilation through ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I have simple structure:

> ./out - binary
>   ./src - source

At `src` I have `Main.java`, where very simple code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I try to compile, with `ProcessBuilder`, there is lines of commands:

```
new EnhancedProcess("javac",
            "-d", Project.getPathOut(),
            "@" + Project.getPathOut() + File.separator + "source.txt").start();
```

> javac -d /home/username/projects/zxcf/out @/home/username/projects/zxcf/out/source.txt

`source.txt` has lines, where catched `*.java` files:

> /home/username/projects/zxcf/src/Main.java

And catch issue:

> /home/username/projects/zxcf/src/Main.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>   Main.java
>   ^
>   1 error

What is this can be?

Comment: Looks like it does not understand the @. Have you tried putting the `-d /home/username/projects/zxcf/out ` in your source.txt file so that javac only has one option? BTW, what is `EnhancedProcess`?

Comment: `EnhancedProcess` -- custom class, where I give him commands and at start method, `ProcessBuilder` run this commands with preferred settings such as catching any errors, etc.

Comment: Haven't tried, I try to do, how in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140512/how-to-compile-multiple-java-files-when-there-are-java-files-in-other-packages

Comment: After putting this lines, I have same effect.