# Maven Test with Evosuite-generated Test Cases

Tags: maven, symbols, evosuite

I am using Evosuite to generate test cases for my app via Maven and I've followed all of the steps that are outlined in the Evosuite documentation.

I see that all of the test classes have been generated and the export copy the classes to the test folder of my project, so I should be able to run mvn test to run the tests, but when I do, I get a series of errors that it cannot find a bunch of classes (it looks like it can't find any of the Evosuite classes from the runtime even though I have the evosuite runtime defined as a dependency in my POM.)

I would love to use Evosuite for all of our apps but if I cannot get the mvn test to run without errors then the product is useless.  Can anybody help with this?  I have gone over the documentation several times and checked everything and it all appears to be configured correctly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already run `mvn evosuite:export` to move them to the ./src/test folder then you may need to compile them using javac so they can be executed by maven. Try using this article to compile them all within one command: [How to compile multiple Java files when there are Java files in other packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140512/how-to-compile-multiple-java-files-when-there-are-java-files-in-other-packages)