# Error FileNotFound - Works on Eclipse but Not on Console Mod

Tags: java, file-io

i Have a prob with a File on my Project Java
My project runs on Eclipse But not a console mode

I Have 3 Packages

pk 1

-> class reads a File

```
   FileInputStream propFile= null;
      Properties properties = new Properties(System.getProperties());
        try {
            propFile = new FileInputStream("file.txt");

            properties.load(propFile);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

->  file.txt

pk2

pk3
-> my main

My code Works On Eclispe but if not at console mode

I don't understand why I can resolve this.

Comment: Does it work if you use your build tool to package your project into a jar file?

Comment: try to use absolute path to file and see if it will work in both cases

Comment: And where is that `file.txt` supposed to be?

Comment: You should refer to this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512603/compiling-multiple-packages-using-the-command-line-in-java), which is similar to yours.

Comment: oh it's work if I use Absolute Path  it's work    Thx so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complement to @JBNizet's answer; here is what you can do using the *new* file API:

```
final Path propertiesFile = Paths.get("file.txt").toAbsolutePath();
final InputStream(in) = Files.newInputStream(propertiesFile);
props.load(in);
```

If the file does not exist, you will get a [`NoSuchFileException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException.html). If you don't have access to it, you will get an [`AccessDeniedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html). Things that the old, legacy file API will not distinguish!

Side note: have a look [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.fr/2014/03/working-with-files-java-6-versus-java-7.html). This will give you lots of reasons to switch to the `Files` API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to read a file named file.txt from the **current** directory. So, before launching the program in the console, type the command

```
ls
```

on Unix or

```
dir
```

on Windows. If there is no `file.txt` listed, then your code will throw a FileNotFoundException.