# How to compile dependent packages

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

I have a project with around 10 classes a few of which depend on each other. When I compile these in the one folder I have no problems. When I separate these classes into separate packages then I can't compile each file as it needs the other to first be compiled to work and vise versa. How do I go about compiling these packages using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at theses questions :

1. [compiling-multiple-packages-using-the-command-line-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512603/compiling-multiple-packages-using-the-command-line-in-java/3512668#3512668)
2. [how-to-compile-multiple-java-files-from-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140512/how-to-compile-multiple-java-files-when-there-are-java-files-in-other-packages)

Hope it helps

Regards